# Rails/Heroku asset partial loading (206) resulting in net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am encountering a problem serving my javascript assets (application.js). In some cases the application.js is loaded with range request headers:

https://variantimagegrouper.herokuapp.com/assets/application-a3ee423959be85930b3400af612a03e5e6e7ecb67f024933780216ac3b172e72.js

Request Headers

- Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
- Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
- Accept-Language:de,en;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4
- Cache-Control:max-age=0
- Connection:keep-alive
- Host:variantimagegrouper.herokuapp.com
- If-Range:Thu, 24 Mar 2016 12:35:03 GMT
  **- Range:bytes=68161-68161**
- Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
- User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2723.2 Safari/537.36

This results in an Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED) and as a result the apps javascript is not loaded correctly.

Hitting Ctrl-F5 (clean cache reload) solves the issue and the application.js is loading correctly, but thats something we have to tell customers regularly.

Any ideas on why the request is made as a range request in the first place and on how to solve that? I feel like it is an issue related to client caching and was thinking about disabling caching at all, but not my favourite solution.

[Partial Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4F98.png)

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: How is it requested? Looks like it requested as some media like audio or video. Is src of script tag?

Comment: Hi @Andrey , it's requested via script tag:<script src="/assets/application-a3ee423959be85930b3400af612a03e5e6e7ecb67f024933780216ac3b172e72.js"></script>